# Connecting to SQL Server Express database with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was able to connect to a database on a server on my network with no problem. However, when I attempt to use SQL Server Express (local db), I keep getting the same error. I created a new solution with only a button and label as to eliminate any other potential issues. I have looked up and tried almost every scenario in stackoverflow and google to no avail .... I decided to post a question, as I am spending way too much time on trying to resolve this. Thanks for any direction

Error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
>   DelWebApplication1.WebForm1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Rozelle\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\DelWebApplication1\DelWebApplication1\WebForm1.aspx.cs:23
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628614
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;

namespace DelWebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ToString();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Label1.Text = "Database Connected!!";
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="DelWebApplication1.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rozelle\Documents\My.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: I would suggest that you go and look for your connection string, I am sure there is something *fishy* with that connection string. :-)

Comment: I think you haven't the connection string with name `MYConnectionString` in your config file.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much, and I tried different fields of the db properties: Name, Connection String etc...., but still no success

Comment: **SHOW US** your `web.config` for this application! You need to have that connection string in your `web.config` - and you obviously don't have that...

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Yeah, I changed the name for this post

Comment: @marc_s  I didn't need to do this when I was connecting a database over a network, but I am a neophyte in c# asp.net, so I may have overlooked something.

Comment: @suffa:check your connection string properly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx just have look on this. I think problem is there only...

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  ....change your connection string name and test

Comment: @Athul I understand how to approach a local conneciton now. Worked!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
<add name="DelWebApplication1.Properties.Settings.MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rozelle\Documents\My.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

with

```
<add name="MYConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Rozelle\Documents\My.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Your connection string name in `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYConnectionString"].ToString();` has a capital `Y`. The connection string names in both your C# codes and Web.config are case sensitive and must be the same.

Comment: Yeah, I changed the original name after-the-fact because the name is kind of sensitive to what I'm working on, and may have created a typo at that time. Thanks anyways.